# Why is Maven's documentation packages in a JAR instead of a ZIP file?

Tags: maven, jar, documentation

As far as I know there is no difference between a JAR file and a ZIP file. They both can be decompressed.

I also know that one can package an API doc in a jar\zip file and hook it up with it's relevant library in eclipse and you've got a Java doc support in eclipse.

But whats the point of packaging a HTML web site in a JAR file ? Is there a standardized way to browse JAR files for html websites ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any particular good reason; it just generally produces jars for everything else (unless it needs to produce a war or ear of course, but they are also types of jars actually), so it's just for consistency's sake.

Comment: Consistency with what ? I'm not very good with Maven but I believe it can output ZIP files as well as JAR\WAR\EAR files.

Comment: True, but JAR files are the most common output (for things that aren't WARs or EARs) I guess.